# I was not able to deploy react native web app to Azure Static Web App via bitbucket

Tags: azure, bitbucket-pipelines, azure-static-web-app

Here is my pipelines `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

options:
  docker: true
  size: 2x

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to test
          deployment: test
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - pipe: microsoft/azure-static-web-apps-deploy:main
              variables:
                APP_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/"
                OUTPUT_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/web-build"
                API_TOKEN: $deployment_token
                APP_BUILD_COMMAND: npx expo export:web

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 4096
```

[The error message was: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.config/devcert' - Click to preview the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9bIC.jpg)

I tried to create artifacts first then make the deployment via `microsoft/azure-static-web-apps-deploy:main` pipe, but it did not work too.

```yaml
image: node:16-alpine

options:
  docker: true
  size: 2x

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install yarn
            - yarn
            - npx expo export:web
          artifacts:
            - web-build/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy to test
          deployment: test
          script:
            - pipe: microsoft/azure-static-web-apps-deploy:main
              variables:
                APP_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/"
                OUTPUT_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/web-build"
                API_TOKEN: $deployment_token
                SKIP_APP_BUILD: "true"

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 4096
```

[The error message was: Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html. - Click to preview the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5ShQ.png)

Comment: Please do NOT use images to paste source code nor logs https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11715259

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following steps:

Azure Account Setup:
Azure Static Web Apps Resource:
Repository Configuration:
Azure Static Web Apps Configuration:
Build Configuration:
GitHub Actions or Azure Pipelines:
CI/CD Configuration:
Secrets and Environment Variables:
Trigger Deployment:
Monitor Deployment:
Debugging:
Iterate and Refine:

Since you're using Bitbucket instead of GitHub, some steps might differ slightly due to differences in CI/CD systems. Be sure to consult the Azure Static Web Apps documentation for Bitbucket integration and explore Azure Pipelines documentation for setting up CI/CD for Bitbucket repositories.